# Order a binded data.frame by decreasing frequency in R

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I know that ordering by frequency is pretty straightforward in R. Given a data.frame `df` and a column `column1` with numerical values:

```
order(df$column1,decreasing=T)
```

My data.frame is the result of having used `rbind()` on smaller data.frames. Each of the original data.frame had a column called `Trial` with values ranging from 1 to nrow(GralData) although some numbers were missing (due to outlier removal). Another column is called `TrialType` and can have two possible character values: `"Regular"` or `"Random"`

What I want to do is create two data.frames out of GralData. One containing only `Regular` in TrialType, and one only containing `Random`. Moreover, I want the new.data.frame to be ordered decreasingly according to the values of `Trial`. This is what I am using:

```
GralData_Regular <- GralData[GralData$TrialType=="Regular" & order(GralData$Trial,decreasing=TRUE),]
```

But, instead this command is ordering the rows keeping in mind the data.frames from which the rows came from. So instead of having all data mixed, order *only* according to the criterion of the value of the `Trial` column, values are ordered first by data.frame and then by order of the value of `Trial`. So the `Trial` column would look something like:

```
 1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,etc...
```

And I want it to be

```
1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,etc...
```

I hope I made myself clear. This is quite a small problem and I am sure I must be missing something basic, but I googled this extensively and didn't find any reference to the problem. Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must do it in two steps :

```
## Subset the original data frame    
GralData_Regular <- GralData[GralData$TrialType=="Regular",]
## Sort it
GralData_Regular <- GralData_Regular[order(GralData_Regular$Trial,decreasing=TRUE),]
```

The `&` operator is used to combine logical vectors. Here your first condition is a logical vector (`GralData$TrialType=="Regular"`), but your second one is numerical (`order(GralData$Trial,decreasing=TRUE)`).

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, you can indicate it to other users by checking the green mark.